# Using CURL to send multipart/alternative email WITH encoder=quoted-printable. How?

Tags: linux, command-line, curl, debug

Below is an example of how I currently send a multipart/alternative with CURL. I write this email in a text editor, save it to a file and use CURL to send the whole thing.

```
To: "John Connor" <john@sky.net>
From: "Sarah Connor" <sarah@sky.net>
Subject: A multipart/alternative text/plain + text/html email
MIME-Version: 1.0 (Created with SublimeText 3)
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="content-boundary-alternative"

Preamble: This is a multipart/alternative message in MIME format.

--content-boundary-alternative
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Good morning.

This is a message in text/plain format.

--content-boundary-alternative
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang=3D"en">
<head>
<meta charset=3D"utf-8">
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html">
</head>
<body>
Good morning.<br/>
<br/>
This is a message in text/html format.<br/>
</body>
</html>

--content-boundary-alternative--
```

Then I send it like this:

```
curl --verbose -ssl smtps://secure.example.com:465 --login-options AUTH=PLAIN --user sarah@sky.net:Letmein#123 --mail-from sarah@sky.net --mail-rcpt john@sky.net --mail-rcpt-allowfails --upload-file complete-message.eml
```

So far so good.

While reading the CURL manpage, more specifically, https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-F I noticed there seems to be a way to properly encode the quoted-printable text/html content for transfer using `-F, --form` `encoder=quoted-printable` so that I don't have to do it manually.

Can anyone provide an adaptation of my approach that includes `encoder=quoted-printable`?

I have a feeling this calls for the headers and the bodies to be placed in separate files but I'm still reading.

Comment: Beginning search for 3rd party quote-printable encoder because wow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send a multipart message using `-F` options, you must use the grouping (?) notation: `"=(;type=multipart/alternative"` / `"=)"` [1].

(it's a single line, but I wrote here this way for clarification)

```
curl --verbose -ssl smtps://secure.example.com:465
    --login-options AUTH=PLAIN
    --user sarah@sky.net:Letmein#123
    --mail-from sarah@sky.net
    --mail-rcpt john@sky.net --mail-rcpt paul@sky.net
    --mail-rcpt-allowfails
    -H @headers.txt
    -F "=(;type=multipart/alternative"
    -F "=<body.txt;encoder=quoted-printable"
    -F "=<body.html;encoder=quoted-printable"
    -F "=)"
    -F "=@files.zip;encoder=base64"
```

In this example, the first part (`=(`) opens a group and everything inside is considered as the same content in different formats (`type=multipart/alternative`). Then two parts (`=<`) are added, a plain text one and an HTML one, both encoded using the quoted-printable algorithm. The group is closed using `=)`.

The next part is not inside the alternative group, and it's attached (`=@`).

When creating the headers file, take into account:

- It should contain those that the receivers see: Date:, From:, Subject:, To:, Cc:, and Reply-To: —if aplicable—.
- cURL takes care of the mandatory headers.
- You can add other headers and they will be added too. If you don't like one of the headers created by cURL, you can add it to the file to override the default.
- New lines must be CR-LF [2].
- I ran a similar command in Windows and I had to encode the headers file in windows-1252 charset, as using UTF-8 broke the email, but your mileage may vary. I didn't tried it on GNU/Linux.

References:

[1] https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-F

[2] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821